# How to resize xamarin forms Gridview image programmatically?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am trying to create a grid view programmatically in Xamarin forms .
But i am unable to resize the grid view Image size with the following Code

```
var img = new Image()
{
    Source = "hamburger.png", //a 600x600 picture
    WidthRequest = 100,
    HeightRequest = 100

};

Content = img;
gridLayout.Children.Add(Content, columnIndex, rowIndex);
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Well you have the Content of the page to be the Image , what you need to make the content to be the Grid itself . 
there are many documentations and examples for how to use Grid.